# WIFI only connects at 6mbps max

Tags: wireless, 20.04, lts

I'm a complete novice on Ubuntu, but wanted to ditch Windows.  I set up Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and everything seemed great.  I selected to keep my Windows installation on a separate partition, as offered by the Ubuntu setup. (Great option)

For the last month or so, I noticed download speeds were much slower than when I first setup Ubuntu and copying data across my LAN was badly affected too.  Like I said I'm a novice on Linux, but I checked the things I knew and noticed the connection speed on 5.2GHz was only 6mbps even thou the laptop is sitting on top of the access point?

I've searched answers on the web, but nothing has helped.....

Please can someone give me some pointers on whats going wrong and how I can fix my slow wifi issues?

Thanks in advance.

```
uname -a 
Linux billysballbag 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo lshw

 description: Notebook
    product: 81BJ (LENOVO_MT_81BJ_BU_idea_FM_ideapad 320-17IKB)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: Lenovo ideapad 320-17IKB
    serial: PF10422D
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0.0 dmi-3.0.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=notebook family=ideapad 320-17IKB frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_81BJ_BU_idea_FM_ideapad 320-17IKB uuid=25BDE230-EAD3-E711-8A95-54E1ADE03662
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: LNVNB161216
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: SDK0J40709 WIN
       serial: PF10422D
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: 0
          version: 6JCN33WW
          date: 06/30/2020
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 6080KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 1842MHz
          capacity: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 8MiB
             capacity: 8MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 24
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: M471A5244CB0-CRC
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: M471A5143SB1-CRC
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 1
             serial: 35B7DED3
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 08
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: UHD Graphics 620
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 07
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:135 memory:92000000-92ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:125 memory:94390000-9439ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-50-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   vendor: Synaptics, Inc.
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@1:4
                   version: 1.64
                   serial: 25dda884e415
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros Communications
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Video
                   product: EasyCamera
                   vendor: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
                   physical id: 8
                   bus info: usb@1:8
                   version: 26.22
                   serial: 0001
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.8.0-50-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.08
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:943b0000-943b0fff
        *-generic:1
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:943b1000-943b1fff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:134 memory:943b2000-943b2fff
        *-raid
             description: RAID bus controller
             product: 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: raid msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:126 memory:943a0000-943a7fff memory:943b4000-943b40ff ioport:5080(size=8) ioport:5088(size=4) ioport:5060(size=32) memory:94300000-9437ffff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:93000000-93ffffff ioport:80000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: 3D controller
                product: GP108M [GeForce MX150]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:138 memory:93000000-93ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:94200000-942fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: enp2s0
                version: 10
                serial: 54:e1:ad:e0:36:62
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-50-generic firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
                resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94204000-94204fff memory:94200000-94203fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 memory:94000000-941fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlp3s0
                version: 31
                serial: e8:2a:44:e6:9a:39
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.8.0-50-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.4.28 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:136 memory:94000000-941fffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:943ac000-943affff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:137 memory:943a8000-943abfff memory:94380000-9438ffff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:943b3000-943b30ff ioport:5040(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0303
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: a
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC  WDS100T2B0A
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 40WD
             serial: 200390460303
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=95a108d3-be4f-49ae-af08-060d2a4677ca logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                version: FAT32
                serial: 764b-302a
                size: 255MiB
                capacity: 259MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=SYSTEM_DRV name=EFI system partition
           *-volume:1
                description: reserved partition
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                serial: 60982d8b-b3de-483b-be82-d434f773ca5e
                capacity: 15MiB
                capabilities: nofs
                configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 3.1
                serial: f4f285b4-b46d-2c4a-b8d6-5b66893347b0
                size: 487GiB
                capacity: 487GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2017-12-08 19:18:14 filesystem=ntfs label=Windows name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:3
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                version: 3.1
                serial: 2a7c253a-2f9a-0844-811c-8ca90d1567c7
                size: 24GiB
                capacity: 24GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2017-12-08 19:26:44 filesystem=ntfs label=LENOVO name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:4
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 5
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,5
                logical name: /dev/sda5
                version: 3.1
                serial: c05712cb-b1d9-f84a-95a1-04f5a8f44527
                size: 994MiB
                capacity: 999MiB
                capabilities: boot precious ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2017-12-08 19:18:20 filesystem=ntfs label=WINRE_DRV name=Basic data partition state=clean
           *-volume:5
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 6
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,6
                logical name: /dev/sda6
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 9203813c-1be8-47fd-8877-f44addb8076e
                size: 417GiB
                capacity: 417GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2020-04-27 11:13:43 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2021-04-22 09:41:20 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2021-04-22 09:41:20 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: b
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD writer
             product: DVD-RW DA8AESH
             vendor: PLDS
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: XL6M
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-battery
       description: Zinc-Air Battery
       product: CRB Battery 0
       vendor: -Virtual Battery 0-
       physical id: 1
       version: 08/08/2010
       serial: Battery 0
       slot: Fake
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: OEM Define 1
       product: OEM Define 5
       vendor: OEM Define 2
       physical id: 2
       version: OEM Define 6
       serial: OEM Define 3
       capacity: 75mWh
```

Comment: thanks ChanganAuto

Comment: First thing to check is the router settings: WPA2-AES is preferred, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.

Comment: I'm runninfg a meshed Eero network router. Using Ethernet back haul.  It says its using WP3 personal as its encryption protocol.

Comment: OK, please wait for the experts :)